# Is it possible to have a list-item not included in the ordered list count in CSS?

Tags: css

Is it possible to have an `<li>` which isn't included in the numbers/count?

so like `1, 2, <li class="ignore-count">, 3, 4, 5`...

Comment: What is this for?

Comment: i have a sponsored `<li>` every 10 items and I don't want to show the number next to it.

Comment: Look into counter-reset from css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by hiding the number with `list-style-type: none;` and "pausing" the counter with `counter-increment: list-item 0;`:

```css
.no-count {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-increment: list-item 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li class="no-count">abc</li>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>abc</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Doesn’t work in safari on iOS

Comment: @chovy What doesn't work? `list-style-type` or `counter-increment`? It seems like counter-increment [should work](https://caniuse.com/?search=counter-increment)...

Comment: it doesn't show a number but it still counts in the list. so `no-count` would be 11 still it just doesn't show 11.